# Node.js listen keyboard and read the line interactively?

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, stdin, keyboard-events

I'm looking for a way to implement something like [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/), in node.js. For Example, I have a SQLite database, I would like to "SELECT" each time user typed something from keyboard input. If user typed "python" python rows will be logged but if typed "pythonn" (just type "n" after "python"), the node program will retrieve "pythonn" so you probably might not get "python" rows.

I searched google, stackoverflow and tested some programs:

```js
var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.on('data', function(chunk) { console.log("Got chunk: " + chunk); });
```

The above program can only read a "character" not line and also you need to type enter key to fire the function.

```js
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    process.exit();
  } else {
    console.log(`You pressed the "${str}" key`);
    console.log();
    console.log(key);
    console.log();
  }
});
console.log('Press any key...');
```

For this one, you don't need to type enter key but this is also for a character reading.

So, how can I do something like that, listen keyboard and read the line interactively? Thanks.